# CodeIgniter with Active Records and or_like

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have an admin panel with a view for all the users info gotten from a Database table named "users".

There's a search box and I use Active records to fetch the data. But there seems to be a problem with that and I can't figure it out. I'm pretty sure it's in the `or_like` part but the error confuses me.

Here is the query I make passing one variable `$data` posting the info from the search box :

```
public function get($data) {

    $this->db->select('id, email, firstname, lastname, usertype, ts_created, ts_last_login, position');

    if (isset($data['query']) && $data['query'] != '') {
        $fields = json_decode($data['fields'], true);

        $this->db->like($fields[0], $data['query']);

        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            $this->db->or_like($field, $data['query']);
        }

    }

    $this->db->limit($data['limit'], $data['start']);
    if (isset($data['sort'])) {
        $sort = json_decode($data['sort'], true);
        $this->db->order_by($sort[0]['property'], $sort[0]['direction']);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get('users');
```

Because it's somewhat a refactoring of an existing program, I had to add a new feature - 'groups' which is not part of the users table so I add the key['groups']=>with values looping the query result :

```
$users = array();
foreach ($query->result_array() as $user) {
    $users[] = array_merge($user, array('groups' =>''));
}

$count = sizeof($users);
//Adding groups id's as values to the group key         
foreach ($this->getGroupsAndUsers() as $group) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if ($users[$i]['id'] == $group['user_id']) {
            //Begin check
            if ($users[$i]['groups'] == '') {
                $users[$i]['groups'] .= $group['group_id'];
            } else {
                $users[$i]['groups'] .= "," . $group['group_id'];
            }
            //End of check 
        }
    }       
}
$result = $users;
return $result;
```

And with passing the final array to the $result variable this should be all, but when I try to search a certain user I get this error:

```
<p>Error Number: 1054</p><p>Unknown column 'groups' in 'where clause'</p><p>SELECT `id`, `email`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `usertype`, `ts_created`, `ts_last_login`, `position`
FROM (`users`)
WHERE  `firstname`  LIKE '%stefan%'
OR  `firstname`  LIKE '%stefan%'
OR  `lastname`  LIKE '%stefan%'
OR  `email`  LIKE '%stefan%'
OR  `position`  LIKE '%stefan%'
OR  `groups`  LIKE '%stefan%'
```

it says that groups is unknown column and it's missing from the select but I'm not sure it's the real problem cause I actually see the groups and have a UI in the admin panel for it. Also, being a MySQL noob, I think it's kind of strange to get a query like this:

```
WHERE  `firstname`  LIKE '%stefan%'
    OR  `firstname`  LIKE '%stefan%'
    OR  `lastname`  LIKE '%stefan%'
    OR  `email`  LIKE '%stefan%'
    OR  `position`  LIKE '%stefan%'
    OR  `groups`  LIKE '%stefan%'
```

I mean, is this the normal behaviour of `or_like` to get the same value?

And at the end, because I'm really lost here, if anyone can help or suggest what could cause this problem would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the results of `$this->db->last_query();` so we can see the actual SQL statement that CI constructed?

Comment: Although I'm not sure I'm using the function right this is the output I get: string(50) "SELECT `user_id`, `group_id` FROM (`users_groups`)"

Comment: If someoen follows and would be of any help, if I add a column 'groups' in the table 'users' without changing anything else it's working...

Comment: so 'groups' isnt a column in the users table? your last comment confuses me with what you said earlier about "I actually see the groups and have a UI in the admin panel for it..."

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for codeigniter like and or_like problem at ellislab forum https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/185983/
Instead of using

```
$this->db->like('location', $your_string);
```

use:

```
$this->db->where('location LIKE', '%'.$your_string.'%');
```

and **or_where** instead of **or_like**.